# How to get browser release date?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dart

In my project I have a problem. I have to implement a date (exactly only the year), when the browser, in which user opens my website, was released (I mean its current version).

> For example if some user opens my website in the last version of
>   Google Chrome 31.0.1650.57, released november 14, 2013, it should show
>   him, that his browser released in 2013. If user opens my website in IE
>   8 (bad dream of all website programmers), it should show him 2009.

Can I get it in any programming language for the web? Please help!

Update: I know one method. I get the browser and the version and then I compare it with table of all browsers, their versions and their release dates of each version (exactly years). But it is really time-consuming and heavy on the size of my websites challenge :/

Comment: There is no such information available as a general rule. You'd have to compile your own list of release dates on a per-browser basis.

Comment: Sorry, that's the only way to do it.

Comment: Since you only need the year, the list doesn't have to be that long. You only need to have the first version of each browser of each year to be able to find the year for each browser version. And probably you don't need *all* browsers, but only those of the last couple of years, or do you want to support Netscape 3 as well?

Comment: You can get a list from Wikipedia which should be good enough: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_web_browsers. I don't see why this would be too heavy for your website to handle.

Comment: Getting the browser version isn’t trivial either. Client-side, you would need to analyze `navigator.userAgent` heuristically. This sounds like an odd assignment. If it is a real-life issue, I think you should explain the original problem that this information is supposed to solve.

Comment: Okay, thank you guys, I thought so. GolezTrol is right, Netscape is outside my app and some other browsers too. It would be fully sufficient to compile it from the first version of the year of each browser all over the world (thanks Pixel Elephant, I have already known the table, but it was really helpful to remind it) starting from the certain year (to everything older show the "old broswer" dialog :D) and then write hundreds of lines...

Comment: if you have compiled the list please share it here, maybe github or gist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc B is correct. You will have to compile your own list.

A library that will help with this task is conditionizr. It's a cousin of Modernizr that is used for user-agent based tests.

http://conditionizr.com/